# Disabling user-select on text input element

Tags: css, sass

I've got a bit of an odd one here, I'm trying to stop users from being able to highlight text within a text input but the standard code below isn't working.

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

jsfiddle illustrating the issue - https://jsfiddle.net/z0L4cj3n/7/

When checking the css within the browser, "user-select: none;" is active but isn't making any difference, is there something else in my css overwriting this behaviour? I've even tried adding the above code to the specific input to no result.

Edit: adding

```
pointer-events: none;
```

is not an option as I have hover effects and jQuery events being triggered by the inputs.

Comment: Looks like this property won't work on `form` elements like input, select, textarea....

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
pointer-events: none;
```

in Css

Comment: That does the trick but I need pointer events set to auto for CSS : hover events and mousedown/mouseover jQuery events